# ArrayList, double contains

Tags: java, arraylist

```
private static boolean moreThanOnce(ArrayList<Integer> list, int number) {
    if (list.contains(number)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How do I use `list.contains` to check if the number was found in the list more than once? I could make a method with `for` loop, but I want to know if it's possible to do using `.contains`. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it just with `contains`. That just tests if the item is anywhere in the list.

You can do it with `indexOf`, though. There are two overloads of `indexOf`, one of which allows you to set a position in the list to start searching from. So: after you find one, start from one after that position:

```
int pos = list.indexOf(number);
if (pos < 0) return false;
return list.indexOf(number, pos + 1) >= 0;
```

Or replace the last line with:

```
return list.lastIndexOf(number) != pos;
```

If you want a more concise way (although this iterates the whole list twice in the case that it's not found once):

```
return list.indexOf(number) != list.lastIndexOf(number);
```

Comment: @Lukas it is simple, but just beware the "although" I added.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Stream`s:

```
private static boolean moreThanOnce(ArrayList<Integer> list, int number) {
    return list.stream()
               .filter(i -> i.equals (number))
               .limit(2) // this guarantees that you would stop iterating over the
                         // elements of the Stream once you find more than one element
                         // equal to number
               .count() > 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, do you think it's possible to do with .contains only? The other user commented "indexOf".

Comment: @Lukas it's not possible with `contains()`.

Comment: @Lukas - It's not possible with `contains()` alone but you can combine `contains()` with some other functions of `List` and make it work.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to count how many times it exist in the list

```
int times = list.stream().filter(e -> number==e).count();
```

Answer (score 2):

The method add of Set returns a boolean whether a value already exists (true if it does not exist, false if it already exists).

Iterate all the values and try to add it again.

```
public Set<Integer> findDuplicates(List<Integer> listContainingDuplicates)
{ 
  final Set<Integer> setToReturn = new HashSet<>(); 
  final Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();

  for (Integer yourInt : listContainingDuplicates)
  {
   if (!set1.add(yourInt))
   {
    setToReturn.add(yourInt);
   }
  }
  return setToReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Disclaimer

Other answers are great because they explain the efficient ways to do it but the sole purpose of this solution is to show how `List::contains` can be used to solve this problem which is the specific requirement of the question. Please also check [the following comment from OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383502/arraylist-double-contains/61383554#comment108589589_61383554) requesting for it.

> Thank you, do you think it's possible to do with .contains only? The
> other user commented "indexOf".

---

## Solution:

It's not possible with `List::contains` alone but you can combine `List::contains` with some other functions of `List` and make it work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        List<Integer> list = List.of(10, 20, 10, 30);
        System.out.println(moreThanOnce(new ArrayList<>(list), 10));
        System.out.println(moreThanOnce(new ArrayList<>(list), 20));
    }

    private static boolean moreThanOnce(List<Integer> list, int number) {
        if (list.size() == 1) {
            return false;
        }
        if (list.get(0) == number && list.subList(1, list.size()).contains(number)) {
            return true;
        }
        return moreThanOnce(list.subList(1, list.size()), number);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
```

Comment: Other answers are great because they explain the efficient ways to do it but this is the only answer on this page which meets the requirement mentioned in the question precisely. Despite that, this answer was downvoted. Probably, the downvoters will never bother to come back and provide the feedback but I'm not deleting my answer hoping that I'll get some feedback from future visitors.

Comment: loving the recursive approach

Answer (score 2):

Others already point out the problem. However, typically you could use the [Collection.frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) method:

```
   private static boolean moreThanOnce(ArrayList<Integer> list, int number) {
        return Collections.frequency(list, number) > 1;
    }
```

Comment: this one is clever and pretty simple